# Is --async flag for gcp sql export supports only one operation simultaneously?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Trying to run some operations with --async flag, eg. 15. But after first operation starts, on the second getting next error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.export.bak) HTTPError 409: Operation failed because another operation was already in progress. Try your request after the current operation is complete.
```

I cannot find this behaviour in the docs. So please explain this for me. I can't run few operations in parallel, am I correct?

The command, which I am using

```
gcloud sql export bak {instance} {bucket} --database={db} --async
```

Just changing DB in the next commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.Most operations in Cloud SQL are executed synchronously  and you can only run one operation at a time. You can perform only one import or export operation at a time for each instance.you can check this [document1](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export#reduce_long-running_import_and_export_processes) & [document2](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/error-messages#:%7E:text=Most%20operations%20in,before%20beginning%20another.) for more information.

As mentioned in the [troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/troubleshooting#export) the error indicates

> There is already a pending operation for your instance. Only one
> operation is allowed at a time. Try your request after the current
> operation is complete.

To avoid the error, you should wait for the first operation to complete before starting the next one. You can [list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/operations/list) all the operations running on the instance,and then use [gcloud sql operations wait](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/operations/wait) on all the other operations.

Comment: Please edit text, exclude links like numbers, normalise them